# Trying to get ip address of server on network so can connect to database

Tags: ip-address, windows-7-x64

I pinged the server in c prompt hoping it would give IP address; I didn't.  How do I obtain the ip address of a server on the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try nslookup and then the server name from the command prompt
i.e.

> nslookup servername

Comment: Thanks!  Why wouldn't it give it to me when I pinged it?

Answer (score 1):

nslookup

will do the trick for you

Here is a list of windows utilities for doing this sort of thing:

http://www.whatismyip.com/doswindows-ip-commands/